Number of paths through square grid that don't intersect the main diagonal (and generalization)
I am wondering how many possible integer step-length paths there are between the 2 endpoints of a right triangle with equally long legs, which is equivalent to half the amount of integer step-length paths through a square grid which may touch, but not intersect the main diagonal. For example, in the case of side length $a=3$ we have the following $5$ paths:
My general problem extens beyond this, and looks at the number of integer step-length paths from $0$ to $(1,...,1)$ possible in the polytope defined by the shape bounded by the function $f:(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\mapsto\frac{1}{n-1}(x_1+...+x_{n-1})$ defined on $x_1\in[0,a],\forall l\geq2,x_l\in[0,x_{l-1}]$, where the problem above corresponds to the special case of $n=2$.
What are the combinatoric objects I need to describe this problem?
The total number of paths through the grid is $\begin{pmatrix}2a\\a\end{pmatrix}$, so a relatively simple upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}2a\\a\end{pmatrix}$, but I haven't gotten much further than that

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

For the $2$-dimensional case, these are called Dyck paths. This is one of several combinatorial problems where the answer is given by the Catalan numbers $C_a=\frac{1}{a+1}\binom{2a}{a}$. From wikipedia:

$C_n$ is the number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with $n\times n$ square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal. A monotonic path is one which starts in the lower left corner, finishes in the upper right corner, and consists entirely of edges pointing rightwards or upwards.


Is there any hope of generalizing this to the paths bounded by the function I defined?

@JohnDoe I don't know, but it's certainly worth calculating the first few values for n=3 and seeing if the sequence is in the OEIS. One way to approach to the 2-D case is to look for the first time you intersect the diagonal, and then note that this reduces to the same problem with smaller a, to obtain the Catalan convolution $C_a=\sum_{i=1}^aC_{i-1}C_{a-i}$. That might give you a recurrence relation for higher n, but I doubt it will have such a nice formula.

I see, thank you.
